# CGAL 4.7 Arrangement of Bezier curves crashes on some inputs

Tags: cgal

I am using the Arrangements package of CGAL 4.7 (64-bit, on Windows) to make 2-d arrangements of Bezier curves for a research project. Unfortunately, I keep experiencing crashes on some -usually (near) degenerate- input, when inserting Bezier curves.

As a simple example I have added the content of two data files that can be read by the Bezier_curve example project provided with CGAL 4.7 (found in .../CGAL-4.7/examples/Arrangement_on_surface_2).
The example crashes for me if I feed it either of the two files.
The example works correctly for me if I use the  Bezier.dat file that comes with it, and on some other test cases that I tried.

*Bezier_crash1.dat* - (very simple test case)

```
1
4 0 100 100 0 100 200 0 100
```

*Bezier_crash2.dat* - (encountered and recorded in my own experiments)

```
6
4  2581853/262144 174874249452033/4398046511104  5673646619833933/35184372088832 2756888783932123/70368744177664  6296137/131072 15962699/131072  105/2 5687589/65536
4  105/2 5687589/65536  7466423/131072 6787657/131072  4884829/32768 1213073/16384  120 13200823/131072
4  120 13200823/131072  13772385/131072 14995659/131072  8262217/131072 13388069/131072  105/2 5687589/65536
4  105/2 5687589/65536  5500343/131072 9362287/131072  5544234768323137/35184372088832 5711427009345511/140737488355328  2581853/262144 183625004300137/2199023255552
4  696761914568827/4398046511104 3007857/16384  1156274078886441/17592186044416 301767055302015/8796093022208  4173567/65536 1173535/8192  97589/1024 428833/4096
4  97589/1024 428833/4096  8317825/65536 541797/8192  10142101/131072 1505657/16384  9752923/131072 1168223/16384
```

I don't know if I should (and am allowed to) post the code of the CGAL example, please let me know if it's needed. I also have more crashing test cases than just these two, but I am hoping that these crashes are a problem with my personal CGAL setup, and that the rest will magically be solved when I fix it :)

Comment: You should submit an [issue](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues) with a minimal example showing the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have made an issue at https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/669 for the curves in Bezier_crash2.dat (not sure if I should add the other file, since it may or may not be a different problem)

Comment: Thanks, hope someone will have a look soon.

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed the bug that most probably causes this problem. It was in the CGAL component that handles Bezier curves, namely, [Arr_Bezier_curve_traits_2.h](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Arrangement_on_surface_2/include/CGAL/Arr_Bezier_curve_traits_2.h).